# Blazor - Adding two values during HTML render

Tags: c#, blazor

This question feels kinda silly but basically:

I have two integers, one of which can change dynamically during runtime.

```
        <table>
             @foreach(var foo in bar)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>...</td>
                    </tr>
                }
        </table>

@code
{
     int v1 = 1; //May change anytime
     List<Model> bar;



public class Model
    {
        public int v2 { get; set; }
    }


}
```

What I need is to display the sum of v1 and v2 (for each object) when the table is rendered. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The display is easy

```
<td>The sum is @(foo.v2 + v1)</td>
```

> one of which can change dynamically during runtime

When it changes as the result of a normal Blazor lifecycle event (ButtonClick or something) : you don't have to do anything.

When it changes by some background process you will have to call StateHasChanged() when it happens.